# F# noob help understanding Lazy and Value

Tags: f#

I'm just beginning F# and haven't really done functional programming since my programming languages class 15 years ago (exception being "modern" C#).

I'm looking at this F# snippet using LINQPad 4:

```
let add x y = x + y

let lazyPlusOne x = lazy add x 1
let e = lazyPlusOne 15
Dump e

let plusOne x = add x 1
let f = plusOne 15
Dump f
```

The output it produces is:

```
Lazy<Int32>  
  Value is not created. 
  IsValueCreated False
  Value 16

16
```

I understand the lazy keyword to delay evaluation until needed, same as C# delayed execution.

What is the meaning of: "Value is not created" here?

Comment: What is the implementation of `Dump`?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I personally am a heavy LINQPad user, having both my own licence and managed to get my company to buy 5 more for my colleagues and like Tomas already mentioned, F# Interactive is currently a better option.

Comment: thanks for the tip - yeah i like linqpad too but i'll go with the suggestion for F#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `lazy` keyword to construct a lazy value (as in your `lazyPlusOne` function), then the result is a value of type `Lazy<int>`. This represents a value of type `int` that is evaluated only when it is actually needed.

I assume that `Dump` function tries to print the value including all its properties - when it starts printing, the value is not evaluated, so `ToString` method prints `Value is not created.` Then it iterates over other properties and when it accesses `Value`, the lazy value is evaluated (because its value is now needed). After evaluation, the property returns 16, which is then printed.

You can replace `Dump` with an F#-friendly printing function (or just use F# Interactive, which is extremely convenient way to play with F# inside Visual Studio with the usual IntelliSense, background error checking etec.)

F#-friendly printing function like `printfn "%A"` doesn't access the `Value` property, so it doesn't accidentally evaluate the value. Here is a snippet from F# Interactive:

```
> let a = lazy (1 + 2);;
val a : Lazy<int> = Value is not created. // Creates lazy value that's not evaluated

> a;;
val it : Lazy<int> = Value is not created. // Still not evaluated!

> a.Value;; // Now, the lazy value needs to be evaluated (to get the Value)
val it : int = 3

> a;;     // After evaluation, the value stays cached
val it : Lazy<int> = 3
```

Comment: thank you - i might have gone down a bad path of "intuition" if not for your response

Answer (score 0):

As of 'Dump e', 'lazyPlusOne 15' has not been evaluated. The 'let e = lazyPlusOne 15' does not require the evaluation of 'lazyPlusOne 15'. We don't yet need to know what e evaluates to yet.
The dump is triggering the evaluation and that is semantically different that just dumping the value after the evaluation.